# comparison between starttime in struct proc and struct psinfo_t in solaris

Tags: c, unix, solaris

In Solaris,
I need to get process start time from kernel space, and from user space.
I find 2 start time for a given process, and they are not equal !
One is located in [proc struct](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/proc.h#139) (link is old but the struct almost identical) and one is on [ps_info struct](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-proc-psinfo/index.html).
During execution, in kernel space, if i use

```
struct proc* iterated_process_ptr = curproc;
```

I get the following struct:

```
typedef struct  proc {
/*
 * Microstate accounting, resource usage, and real-time profiling
 */
hrtime_t p_mstart;      /* hi-res process start time */
```

And if i fill psinfo_t from user space struct like this:

```
char psfile[64];
psinfo_t psinfo;
sprintf(psfile, "/proc/ProcessID/psinfo");
if ((fd = open(psfile, O_RDONLY)) >= 0)
    if (read(fd, &psinfo, sizeof(psinfo_t)) != -1)
```

the struct psinfo is filled, it looks like:

```
typedef struct psinfo {
timestruc_t pr_start;   /* process start time, from the epoch */
```

What is the difference between 2 start times ?

If i do it for the same process, the values are different, this means that hi-res process start time is different from process epoch start time.

What is hi-res process start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p_mstart` field of the structure [is filled in here  in OpenSolaris (see line 1008)](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/os/fork.c#997) under the `fork()` system call:

```
    /*
     * Make proc entry for child process
     */
    mutex_init(&cp->p_splock, NULL, MUTEX_DEFAULT, NULL);
    mutex_init(&cp->p_crlock, NULL, MUTEX_DEFAULT, NULL);
    mutex_init(&cp->p_pflock, NULL, MUTEX_DEFAULT, NULL);
#if defined(__x86)
    mutex_init(&cp->p_ldtlock, NULL, MUTEX_DEFAULT, NULL);
#endif
    mutex_init(&cp->p_maplock, NULL, MUTEX_DEFAULT, NULL);
    cp->p_stat = SIDL;
    cp->p_mstart = gethrtime();
    cp->p_as = &kas;
```

[Per the man page for `gethrtime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1477/gethrtime-9f.html#scrolltoc):

> The `gethrtime()` function returns the current high-resolution real
>   time. Time is expressed as nanoseconds since some arbitrary time in
>   the past; it is not correlated in any way to the time of day

So, the `p_mstart` field is filled with a time that can be used to determine exactly how many nanoseconds ago the process started, via a difference with with the return value of a current call to `gethrtime()`:

```
hrtime_t duration = gethrtime - p->p_mstart;
```